# DLLMain The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call

Tags: c++, dll

When I try injecting the C++ dll into the process I end up getting the following error

"Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function pointer declared with a different calling convention."

I'm certain that the cause of the error is because of the DLLMain I very well could be wrong.

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain (HMODULE hDll, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    switch( dwReason )
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Inject, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

This is the inject function

```
VOID Inject() {
    QWORD time;
    DWORD id, pid;
    HANDLE hSs, hThread;
    HMODULE hMono;
    THREADENTRY32 t;
    FILETIME CreationTime, ExitTime, KernelTime, UserTime;
    CONTEXT context = { CONTEXT_CONTROL };
    // poll for mono

    while ((hMono = GetModuleHandle("mono.dll")) == NULL) Sleep(10);


    mono_security_get_mode = (DWORD (__cdecl *)(void))GetProcAddress(hMono, "mono_security_get_mode");
    mono_security_set_mode = (void (__cdecl *)(DWORD))GetProcAddress(hMono, "mono_security_set_mode");
    mono_domain_get = (PVOID (__cdecl *)(void))GetProcAddress(hMono, "mono_domain_get");
    mono_domain_assembly_open = (PVOID (__cdecl *)(PVOID,PCHAR))GetProcAddress(hMono, "mono_domain_assembly_open");
    mono_assembly_get_image = (PVOID (__cdecl *)(PVOID))GetProcAddress(hMono, "mono_assembly_get_image");
    mono_class_from_name = (PVOID (__cdecl *)(PVOID,PCHAR,PCHAR))GetProcAddress(hMono, "mono_class_from_name");
    mono_class_get_method_from_name = (PVOID (__cdecl *)(PVOID,PCHAR,DWORD))GetProcAddress(hMono, "mono_class_get_method_from_name");
    mono_runtime_invoke = (PVOID (__cdecl *)(PVOID,PVOID,PVOID *,PVOID))GetProcAddress(hMono, "mono_runtime_invoke");


    // mono executes with thread local data, get the main thread.
    id = NULL;
    pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
    hSs = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, pid);

    t.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

    if (hSs) {
        // set time to max value so we can find the oldest thread
        time = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
        if (Thread32First(hSs, &t)) {
            do {
                if (t.th32OwnerProcessID == pid) {
                    hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, t.th32ThreadID);
                    if (hThread) {
                        if (GetThreadTimes(hThread, &CreationTime, &ExitTime, &KernelTime, &UserTime)) {
                            // nasty casting lol
                            if (time > *(PQWORD)&CreationTime) {
                                time = *(PQWORD)&CreationTime;
                                id = t.th32ThreadID;
                            }
                        }
                        CloseHandle(hThread);
                    }
                }
            } while (Thread32Next(hSs, &t));
        }
    }
    else {
        Deject("Couldn't acquire the main thread.");
        return;
    }

    if (id) {
        // hijack the main thread and have it inject our c# code
        hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION | THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME | THREAD_GET_CONTEXT | THREAD_SET_CONTEXT, FALSE, id);
        if (hThread) {
            SuspendThread(hThread);
            if (GetThreadContext(hThread, &context)) {
                dwReturn = context.Eip;
                context.Eip = (DWORD)MonoInject;
                SetThreadContext(hThread, &context);
            }
            ResumeThread(hThread);
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
        else {
            Deject("Couldn't hijack the main thread, BALLS!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if this were working, you should not call `CreateThread()` inside of `DllMain()`. MSDN's documentation explicitly states as much: [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx): "*You should never perform the following tasks from within DllMain: ... •Call CreateThread. Creating a thread can work if you do not synchronize with other threads, but it is risky.*"

Comment: What does the declaration of `Inject()` look like? Your type-cast to `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` might be hiding a declaration mistake that would otherwise cause a compiler error. You should strive to avoid type-casting when possible, let the compiler fail if it needs to. It is an indication that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem with a trivial `Inject` function that does nothing? If not, then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Remy thank you for your response. I acknowledge the fact that there is mistakes made within my cpp class due to the fact that I am trying to get a "Mono Injector" working with source that I found on a thread post. I updated the post with the inject function.

Comment: Hi David. I just tried that now and removed everything inside the "Inject" function and complied it then injected the dll. And I can confirm that there was no error this time.

Comment: `VOID Inject() {` That can't be right. Did you mean `DWORD WINAPI Inject (LPVOID param) {`?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: I tried to replace "VOID Injector() {" with "DWORD WINAPI Inject (LPVOID param) {" as you said. And I'm now getting the error "Inject function must return a value".

Comment: Hi Eric. I was unable to locate the exact line of which the error occurs due to the fact that the error happens after injection of the dll. Meaning that i'm unable to locate the line due to the fact its outside of Visual Studio 2010 that I am using to compile the dll. However from what David said to do I was able to narrow the location of the error down to the "Inject" function.

Comment: @BenUrquhart Just open a second instance of Visual Studio and attach a debugger to the second process. Or hard-code a call to [DebugBreak()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and let Visual Studio pop open for you.

Comment: Why do you need to cast the function pointer? If you're casting a function pointer, that means you're Doing Something Wrong(TM).

Comment: Hi immibis. By function pointer if you are referring to context.Eip = (DWORD)::MonoInject; I have to have that in order for the injection to proceed.